# Creality Ender 3 V2 little yellow switch on power supply

Tags: creality-ender-3, power-supply

I just bought and built a Creality Ender 3 V2.  The last step of the setup is to flip this little yellow switch on the power supply to be either 115 V or 230 V.  From my other research, I think that I have to flip the switch to 115 V because I live in the US. Since US standard outlets give 120 V of electricity and not 115 V, I am confused.  Why is 115 V "correct" if the voltage I will supply is actually 120 V?  Will this extra 5 volts burn out the printer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It won't burn it out. The voltage is between 110 to 125. Power supplies are designed to work in that range. So sometimes you'll see appliances rated for 110 V, 115 V, 120 V... they actually are all the same.

Comment: Came to answer this, but you beat me to it! The only thing I would've added was this [link](https://www.buildmyowncabin.com/electrical/electrical-faq/difference-voltages-110-220.html) that explains that the 115 V can suggest that it will operate despite the voltage drop in the cord between printer (or other appliance) and outlet.

Comment: so, just to make sure I understand, you are saying that American outlets actually output between 110V and 125V and appliances with ratings anywhere in that range are probably the same?

Comment: Not probably, it's standard for any appliances with the 230/120 V rating switch. So the 230 side would work in New Zealand or elsewhere that has a 240 V rating.

Comment: @brothman01, go visit [diy.se] for 10,000 questions (give or take...) about the varying voltages. This answer is 100% correct. The US has officially been 120/240v for about 40-50 years, but people still talk about 110v and 220v. Most devices will function just fine with about a 10% variation in voltage, and with international markets, most are actually auto-sensing and will switch internally between 120v & 240v. It's rather surprising that you have to manually flip the switch to specify.